# How to end a regular expression when one of several possible phrases are found?

Tags: python, regex

[image: This is my code right now]

I basically know nothing about regex but with the help of Google I'm attempting to use it to create an address parser that only extracts the street number and name (ex. 123 Random Boulevard) from a string of text (ex. "Hey I live at 123 Random Boulevard if you were wondering". To do this, I created a list of words that street names end with (ex. avenue, street, place, way, etc.).

What syntax do I use in  the 6th line of my code (regex_partialaddress) to get the regular expression to end upon encountering one of these words from the list?

Thanks in advance—any help is much appreciated.

So far, I have attempted to run the following lines of code

```
regex_partialaddress = "[0-9]{1,4} $['Way', 'Ave', 'Rd', 'Blvd', 'St.', 'Pl.', 'Dr.', 'Cir.', 'Ln', 'Ct', 'Hwy', 'Pkwy', 'Plaza', 'Highway', 'Court', 'Lane', 'Circle', 'Boulevard', 'Street', 'Road', 'Avenue', 'Drive', 'Place', 'Temple', 'Parkway']{1}"

re.findall(regex_partialaddress, "Hey I live at 123 Random Boulevard if you were wondering")
```

It compiled but it was not successful

Comment: From what documentation do you get such a "regex" syntax as `$['Way', 'Ave', ...]`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is separate the words you want to search for with pipe ('|') characters and place them inside a set of parens.  Here's how to do that with a list of valid street types:

```
import re

street_types = ['Way', 'Ave', 'Rd', 'Blvd', 'St.', 'Pl.', 'Dr.', 'Cir.', 'Ln', 'Ct', 'Hwy', 'Pkwy', 'Plaza',
                'Highway', 'Court', 'Lane', 'Circle', 'Boulevard', 'Street', 'Road', 'Avenue', 'Drive', 'Place',
                'Temple', 'Parkway']

# Escape the '.' characters so that they match literally rather
# than matching any character.
street_types = [st.replace('.', r'\.') for st in street_types]

str = "123 Random Boulevard"

regex_partialaddress = fr"[0-9]{{1,4}} \w+ ({'|'.join(street_types)})"

m = re.match(regex_partialaddress, str)
if m:
    print(f"Street type: {m.group(1)}")
```

Result:

```
Street type: Boulevard
```

UPDATE: @tripleee pointed out that there are periods in the street types that should be matched literally.  Leaving them as is will cause them to match any character in that position.  I added a preprocessing step to the code to escape the periods so that the produce the right behavior in the regex.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you want to `re.escape` the values, so as to quote the dot in `St.`, `Dr.`, `Cir.` for example so that it only matches a literal dot, not any character.

Comment: @triplee Ah yes, you are abs correct.  An exercise left for the poster, lol :). Actually...I fixed it.